# Drive Letter Variable in Filepath

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I created an ISO containing a file named `AutoRun.exe`. I've created a PowerShell script to mount and save the mounted drive letter to `letter.txt`.

```
$Mounted= Mount-DiskImage -PassThru "C:\Users\Skulliam\Documents\DiskImage.iso"
$DriveLetter = ($Mounted | Get-Volume).DriveLetter
$DriveLetter | Out-File letter.txt
```

I then attempted to access the drive letter from `letter.txt`. For example, if it mounted the ISO to drive F, the batch would run `F:\Autorun.exe`.

```
for /f "Delims=" %%a in (letter.txt) do (
     set DRIVE=%%a
)
START %DRIVE%:\AutoRun.exe
pause
```

The error states

> Windows cannot find ':\AutoRun.exe'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Out-File` creates the output file in Unicode format, which your batch script can't process. Change the output encoding to `Ascii`:

```
... | Out-File 'letter.txt' -Encoding Ascii
```

With that said, why do you use two different scripts, and different languages on top of that? You could run the executable from PowerShell like this:

```
& "${DriveLetter}:\Autorun.exe"
```

If you need to run the scripts separately from each other you could get the drive in a second PowerShell Script like this:

```
$DriveLetter = Get-Content 'letter.txt'
& "${DriveLetter}:\Autorun.exe"
```

Comment: This should work well, and it does, but it expects the support files (ini, cfg) to be where the Powershell was executed (in this case my desktop). Any work arounds?

Comment: What "support files" are you talking about?

Comment: "autorun.inf" and "AutoRunGUI.dll"

Comment: Change the working directory to where the files are located.

Comment: How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Your Batch-Code is correct. New letter.txt file with the Letter C in it will start C:\AutoRun.exe

Did you try this? If it works, your Problem is within your PowerShell script.

I can not execute this PowerShell script, because my system does not recognize "Mount-DiskImage" and "GetVolume".

Comment: The Powershell works just fine; I can compare the text document to the actual iso Drive Letter and they are equal. Somewhere, something's going wrong with running the executable itself...

Comment: maybe you need to set the execution path?